# Not able to configure Grunt -contrib-watch 's liverload

Tags: yeoman-generator, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm trying to enable livereload feature of grunt-contrib-watch .
Tried various possibilities ,also tried the solution mentioned in https://gist.github.com/adion/7580522

but nothing seems to work .
I have generated this app using yeoman using knockout generator .
I tried adding script as mentioned in http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Grunt-Live-reloading-with-external-server.html
nothing seems to work .
Please help in configuring the same.

Thanks
Sahithi

Comment: watch: {
      gruntfile: {
        files: '<%= jshint.gruntfile.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:gruntfile'],
  options :{
   livereload:true
  }
      },
      src: {
        files: '<%= jshint.app.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:src', 'qunit']
      },
      test: {
        files: '<%= jshint.test.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:test', 'qunit']
      },
   scripts:{
   files: ['css/*', 'js/*'],
   tasks: ['concat', 'cssmin', 'uglify'],
   options :{
    livereload:8000
   }
   }
    },

Comment: connect: {
      development: {
        options: {
          keepalive: false,
        }
      },
   livereload: {
        options: {
          middleware: function( connect ) {
            return [
              lrSnippet,
              mountFolder(connect, './')
            ];
          }
        }
      }
   }

Comment: I have added gruntfile code for watch and connect code of gruntfilejs